# How to add a property to TTabSheet such that it can be used at design time with TPageControl

Tags: delphi, tpagecontrol, ttabsheet, class-helpers

I would like to add "MyProperty" to TTabSheet and work with it at design time. However if I subclass it I fear I will need to also subclass TPageControl, since it internally creates/manages the TTabSheets.

I believe this would require duplicating the TTabSheet management code to reference TMyTabSheet instead of TTabSheet, since it will need to invoke TMyTabSheet.create.  This feels like something I will regret when a new version of Delphi updates TPageControl and I forget to update TMyPageControl.

I am also researching "class helpers" as another option.

Does anyone have advice on how to best accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: will this be a real property or only one simulated in design-time ? can you do without subclassing TTabSheet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type Helpers are merely compile-time sugar, they would cause no effect over the already compiled code, that stock VCL is together with `TPageControl` and `TForm`. That is a dead-end.

However you have a slight misconception here that `TPageControl... internally creates... the TTabSheets`. Indeed, when you create the sheets by the means of `TPageControl` itself, like right-clicking it and selecting "New Tab" that si what happens. But when you create the living form object out of DFM file (or DFM resource in your compiled EXE) that is `TForm` itself that creates ALL the components, including both page control and its tabsheets.

Just see my answer at [How to efficiently let a `ParentFont = False` child control to use same font name as parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306195) - that would show you how far it is about the *owner* - `TForm`, not about `TPageControl` or other *parent* components when it comes about selecting specific classes for the actual tabs or other elements..

So you are free to pursue subclassing tabsheets only.

- Create the `TMyTabsheet = class(TTabSheet)` component
- Create and install into IDE the *design-time package* that would introduce new subclassed tab sheet to Delphi Form Editor
- In your form put the stock `TPageControl` and create all the needed tabs regular way
- in IDE form Editor right-click over the form free space and in the menu do the "View As Text Alt-F12" command - you would see the text content of your form's DFM file
- in those DFM sources find your tab sheets and change their stock `TTabSheet` class to be your derived sub-class
- right-click the text editor and choose "View As Form Alt-F12" command
- If all was done correct then Delphi would recreate the form with your new-class sheets now. Find your new properties in Object Inspector and change them.
- Now switch to .Pas sources of your form and find the declarations of those tab sheets and change their type too. That is only required if you would have to access your new properties from the Delphi sources. If not you can leave their declaration as `TTabSheet` in pas-file as your class is direct descendant from it. You may leave those declarations as they were - but then you would have to add `RegisterClass(TMyTabSheet);` call into the very `initialization` section at the bottom of your unit, so when the form would construct itself out of the DFM it would be able to find the class implementation by the name. If you would change the declaration (at least one of those) then your form would automagically call all needed `RegisterClass` before streaming out of DFM. Choose any option you like.
- Optionally and later, extend your design-time package to find and hijack IDE Form Editor's right-click menu for `TPageControl` and add "New My Subclassed Tab" command there. Just to avoid manual post-factum DFM editing. if you would do it often

> This feels like something I will regret when a new version of Delphi updates TPageControl

After you created and tuned the form and saved it into DFM - it would be `TForm` that creates all the components out of the saved DFM-data, and that includes your tabs too. Unless very improbable event EMBT would kill the whole VCL streaming (made back in Delphi 1 in 1995) and redesign it from scratch (killing all the compatibility with existing Delphi sources at once), there should be no problem with forward compatibility with specifying your class in DFM. It is just the standard way VCL is designed - to get specific component types from the DFM.

Comment: Works as advertised!  I was aware of the trick of editing the DFM to quickly change types, but I did not expect that swapping out 'TTabSheet' for 'TMyTabSheet' wouldn't fight 'TPageControl'.  Thanks @Arioch-the!

Comment: There was no fighting, there was utilizing default methods. Different sheets in page control are like different controls in form. They differ in details, but they share critical commonalities. See Liskov substitution. Being able to put different button classes ( different but all derived from twincontrol "standard") over a panel is not much different from different sheets in page control.

Comment: @user1627960 I fixed one oversight in my answer, an important implementation detail which h initially forgot to mention